# Is it possible to embed activemq broker into my servlet-container?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I have a few tomcat servlet-containers and I need to deploy activemq within one of them to allows the other containers connect to that broker. All the `tomcat`s runnning on the same machine.

I need to avoid deploying a standlone message broker now, beucase it's not allowed by out producion evironment.

To be more specifiec, I'm using spring framework and as far as I understood we can write the following in order to start the embedded broker:

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

// configure the broker
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");

broker.start();
```

But does it allow to connect to the broker not only within the same application, but also from the other tomcat instances using the 61616 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that allows remote connection on port 61616.

At Apache Camel we have also an example of embedding ActiveMQ broker in a WAR application, and using the xml configuration of ActiveMQ. You can find it here: http://camel.apache.org/activemq-camel-tomcat.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't know what Apache Camel is. Is that neccesary to deploy it to use embedded broker?

Comment: No it is not. But configuring ActiveMQ using XML is often easier as all the documentation is about this and its the main configuration way. You can also do it in Java code but its more verbose to do.